# Dropdown selected value is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using Webforms. I have a form with a country `DropDownList`:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Country" 
     DataValueField="CountryID" DataTextField="CountryDisplayName"/>
```

I fill it in code behind:

```
var countries = CountryService.GetCountries();
countries.Insert(0, new CountryInfo { CountryName = "", CountryDisplayName = "", CountryID = 0 });

Country.DataSource = countries;
Country.DataBind();
```

Everything is ok but now I'm trying to move this control to separate control.

I've moved it and it is filled with countries.

The problem is that I'm using postback to get filled form and when dropdown in a separate control `SelectedValue` is always empty.

What could be cause of the problem?

Comment: can you show the code that you are using in the `Page_Load` event, there are several ways to do this if you want to not use postbacks, for example `UpdatePanel, __DoPostBack()` which is a javascript function, `HiddenField , Session Variables` try to do a Stackoverflow google search on how to create javascript function to capture DropDown Selected values or how to use UpdatePanel

Comment: It looks like you have missed to wrap `GetCountries()` bind method inside `!IsPostback`. This is a common mistake we usually do. Check `Page_Load` event and see if `!IsPostback` is there or not.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the postback is removing the information or your databind is replacing it.

1. Have you tried wrapping the country.databind() in an !IsPostback?
2. Have you tried adding an SQLDatasource in the markup, link it to the Dropdown, adding AutoPostback and see if it works?

See below:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ID="Country" 
 DataValueField="CountryID" DataTextField="CountryDisplayName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"/>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXXConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXXConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="XXXX">
```